# Link to older Rails documentation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

For the love of all things holy, can someone please post a link to the Rails 3.2 documentation?  Like this http://api.rubyonrails.org/, but rails 3.2, not rails 4.  Not the [rails guide for 3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.14/), I have no problem finding that, I need the official documentation.

Every link I find sends me to the Rails 4 documentation, including old links that were supposed to be for Rails 3.  The Rails 4 docs don't provide a link to any other Rails docs. I don't know how it is possible to make something like that unGoogleable, but I can't find it.

While you are at it, if you want to post a list of links to the official documentation to other versions of Rails it might be a good resource.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just append the version to the url, using "v" followed by the full rails version. Like this:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/

Comment: Awesome, I am going to accept this. Unfortunately you need to know the most recent release, it doesn't automatically point to it if you just do http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/

Comment: I don't know when it changed, but you can now just include the minor version and the docs will redirect to the most recent patch version :)